# Dynamically name Array based off other variable values

Tags: javascript, express

I am attempting to name an array that is based off a var referencing a room number, and a userID. The rooms and userId's change, so I need to be able to create many arrays based off how many users are logged in.

I know the following code won't work, but so you get the idea of what I am trying to achieve:

```
var room + userId = new [];
```

How would I go about doing this in JavaScript? This is for the back-end, not browser.

Comment: Use object: `var obj = {}; obj['room' + userId] = 'Something';`

Comment: `var room + userId = new [];` Too may errors

Comment: Using object would be efficient.For eg var obj= { roomId : 1 ,userId : 'abc' ,count : no_of_users } . And increment the count when a user is added to the same room.

Comment: I am not sure that is what I am attempting to do. I am trying to name my array the value of room + userId. eg: room = 1, userId =2 so the array would be:  12 [something in array].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

I've researched this myself before, I found that it is not how the language is designed to be used.

The closest you can come up with is by using key value pair.

```
var array = [];
array[room + userId] = [];
```